# Converting ascii substr to int

Tags: c++

first year college having problem converting ascii into int.

The problem is this piece of code

unsigned short iminutes = ((minutes[3]-48)*10) + (minutes[4]-48);

When I run this on codeblocks at home it returns an incorrect value, when I run it again I get a different incorrect value.

When I run it at on Borlands at college, the screen just ups and disappears before I can read it, so I can't use the system clock here either.

It's Easter hols now so even though I'm at college, I can't annoy my tutors because they're not.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
//#include <time.h>
//#include <ctype.h>


using namespace std;

int main() {

bool q = false;


do {

// convert hours to minutes ... then total all the minutes
// multiply total minutes by $25.00/hr
// format (hh:mm:ss)


string theTime;

cout << "\t\tPlease enter time  " << endl;
cout <<"\t\t";
cin >> theTime;
cout << "\t\t"<< theTime << "\n\n";

string hours = theTime.substr (0, 2);
cout <<"\t\t"<< hours << endl;
unsigned short ihours = (((hours[0]-48)*10 + (hours[1] -48))*60);
cout << "\t\t"<< ihours << endl;

string minutes = theTime.substr (3, 2);
cout <<"\t\t"<< minutes << endl;
unsigned short iminutes = ((minutes[3]-48)*10) + (minutes[4]-48);
cout << "\t\t" << iminutes << endl;

cout << "\n\n\t\tTotal Minutes  " <<(ihours + iminutes);
cout << "\n\n\t\tTotal Value  " <<(ihours + iminutes)*(25.00/60) << "\n\n";

}

while (!q);

cout << "\t\tPress any key to continue ...";
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set minutes to be a substring of theTime. So minutes has 2 characters. The first one starting at position 0 within minutes.

So this

```
unsigned short iminutes = ((minutes[3]-48)*10) + (minutes[4]-48);
```

is wrong as it accesses characters 3 and 4 in minutes which don't exist, because minutes is only two characters long. It only has characters as positions 0 and 1.

should be this

```
unsigned short iminutes = ((minutes[0]-48)*10) + (minutes[1]-48);
```

or you could use this:

```
unsigned short iminutes = ((theTime[3]-48)*10) + (theTime[4]-48);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even though you get the characters at position 3 and 4 from the original string, the new string is just two characters (i.e. only have index 0 and 1).

Comment: Another problem is that he's subtracting `48`, rather than `'0'`.  (And also that he's not validating that he has digits to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

```
istringstream iss(theTime.substr(0, 2));
iss >> ihour;
```